# If $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the $X$is a Borel set because $X = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets

In Reference 1 (p. 33), Axler writes the statement: If $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and there exists a Borel measurable function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the $X$ must be Borel set [because $X = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$]. We suppose that $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space. Below is my attempt to prove that statement. In particular, to show that $X = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$.

By Assumption, $f$ is a Borel measurable function. Then using the Theorem on ``Condition for measurable function'' Reference 1 (p. 32), we can write that $f^{-1}((a,\infty)) \in \mathcal{S}$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.

The condition is **for all** $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then let $a = k \in \mathbb{N}$ and
we can write:
\begin{equation}
\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty) = (-\infty,\infty) = \mathbb{R}. 
\end{equation}
For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $f^{-1}((-k,\infty)) \in \mathcal{S}$, using algebra of inverse image,
we can write:
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty))= \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} f^{-1}(-k,\infty)) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \in \mathcal{S}
\end{equation}
and by Assumption, we obtain that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Borel set.

Consider $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty))$. Using algebra of inverse image we obtain:
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty)) = X \setminus f^{-1}(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty)) 
\end{equation}
but $\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty) = \emptyset$

Hence, with $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, the above equation becomes
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset = X \setminus f^{-1}(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty)) 
\end{equation}

By the definition of a complement of any set we have that
\begin{equation}
X = f^{-1}(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} (-k,\infty)) 
\end{equation}
and we obtain:
\begin{equation}
X = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) 
\end{equation}

Since $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \in \mathcal{S}$ is a Borel set, then $X \in \mathcal{S}$ and is also a Borel set. This completes the proof.

Hoping this question is appropriate for this forum, I would like to know if the above proof is correct even if it is a bit long.

Reference: 1 - Axler, S., ``Measure, Integration & Real Analysis'', Springer Open, Cham, 2020.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. What does it mean to say that $f: X \to \mathbb R$ is Borel measurable? What is the $\sigma-$ algebra on $X$ w.r.t. which you are defining measurability? If you are taking Borel $\sigma-$ algebra of  the subspace topology then the statement is completely wrong.